# How exactly does the gold sharing for ward kills work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Patch 3.9 added [ward kill gold sharing](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold#Destroying_a_Ward). That is, whenever a ward is killed, the killer gets a share of the gold, and the person who revealed the ward gets a share of the gold. This means that a support who places a Vision Ward at Dragon will get a share of the 30 gold reward if a team mate clears a ward there.

What happens if more than one person reveals the ward? For instance, if a ward is revealed by both a pink ward and an Oracle's Elixir? How will the gold be split?

Comment: This is from my own believe, that's why I'm posting this as a comment rather then an answer. You have two parts on the gold. 15 gold is for the revealing, and another 15 for destroying it. I think that both parts get shared between the players participating. But I might be wrong though. Good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patchnote says:

> The killer of the ward gains 50% of the ward's base gold value. Nearby
>   allied champions with Oracle's Elixir, or allied champions that placed
>   Vision Wards nearby, split 50% of the ward's base gold value.

That is to say that if multiple players reveal the same ward, they share the 15 gold reward.

Comment: Hmmm... so can you exploit this so that two people get eight gold, or four people get four gold? Or would they round the values down... the questions...

Comment: Don't really know (pending test?). But the effort you have to put in the realisation for the reward you get might not be worth it. Wild guess, I think it would be rounded down.

Comment: Ah, I missed that in the patch notes. I'm curious as well about how the gold is split, though I'm not sure I'd call it an exploit. Also, this means that if someone kills a ward with oracle's that is also revealed by somebody else's pink ward, the killer will receive 75% and the other person will receive 25%, right?

Answer (score 1):

Before, 30 gold was given to the killer of the ward. Now, 15 gold is given to the killer and 15 to the *first* person who reveals it.

Comment: You mean it was 25 before, they increased the base reward.

Comment: I don't remember if it was 25 before, but now it is 15/15, so they did increase it...